# low pass filter on ongoing samples

Tags: lowpass-filter

My application requires to sample a sensor and send the samples out in real time, without saving the samples.

I am required to run a low pass filter on the samples, but here is the problem cause if I want to do it on 20 samples for example then I will not be able to send out the samples each after I got it as required, and when I send them immediately each after I got it I use an ongoing average on 10 samples but that wasn't enough.

what low pass filter algorithm is the best for this application?

what is the accepted way to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

Try the Exponential, or First-order filter:

Y[n] = dY[n-1] + (1-d)X[n]

- Y[n] is the current output
- Y[n-1] is the previous output
- X[n] is the current input
- d is the damping factor

The damping factor is a number between 0 and 1. If d = 0, the output is just equal to the input, and no filtering (smoothing) takes place. The closer d is to 1, the greater the amount of filtering (smoothing).

Here is an example: The input signal is a Sine function with amplitude +- 100, added to that is random noise of +-10. To filter out the noise we run the data through the filter equation first with d = 0.5 and then d = 0.8
[image]

More details with code and second and third order filters available here >> [ST Community- answer](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D53W00000A39L6SAJ/low-pass-filter-on-ongoing-samples)